# Element not interactable in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I want Selenium to write `hello` in this username field

[image: this username field]

```
<input autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" aria-invalid="false" id="email" aria-describedby="id-3" class="w100 inputform-field" value="">
```

However, it is not working for me. I tried:

```
driver.get('https://account.proton.me/signup?plan=free&billing=12&currency=EUR&language=en')

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="email"]'))).send_keys('hello')
```

What am I doing wrong? Error: `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable`

Comment: What happens when you visit that url in a regular browser session?  Is that input field working as expected?

Comment: Yes it does. I now also tried to use the full XPATH but still it's not working. `/html/body/div[1]/label/div[2]/div/div[1]/input` :(

Comment: Because it's in an iframe omfg. Going to try to switch into it - _

Comment: The email input field you are trying to access has 2 references. One is hidden and another is inside iframe. The one you want is inside iframe. So you need to switch to iframe first     WebElement iframe=driver.findElement(By.Xpath“//iframe[contains(@class,'h-custom’)]”));      Then, simply try driver.findElement(By.Xpath("(//*[@id='email']")[last()])).send_keys("hello");    @Carolin99

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  can try below line of code

```
driver.get('https://account.proton.me/signup?plan=free&billing=12&currency=EUR&language=en')
driver.maximize_window()

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//iframe[@class='challenge-width-increase h-custom']"))
email1=driver.find_element(By.ID,"email")
email1.send_keys("hello")
```

**Import**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```